# Cannot import a function in another file (node.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, router, es6-modules

I have an issue that I can't resolve. I'm working with node.js and I simply want to use an export router function in another file .

Here is the code from the import file:

```
import express from "express";
import * as zoneInstance from "../../controllers/objectInstance/zoneInstance.js";
import { mobilityRouter } from "../../controllers/routerFunction/routerLogic.js";

const router = express.Router();

/* Router for mobility render
// const mobilityRouter = (zone, instance) => {
//     return (
//         router.get("/mobility/" + zone, instance)
//     );
// } */

mobilityRouter(zoneInstance.shoulder.zone, zoneInstance.shoulder.mobilityRender());
```

---

Here is the code from the export file:

```
import express from "express";
const router = express.Router();

// Router for mobility render
export const mobilityRouter = (zone, instance) => {
    return (
        router.get("/mobility/" + zone, instance)
    );
}

// Router for reinforcement render
export const reinforcementRouter = (zone, instance) => {
    return (
        router.get("/reinforcement/" + zone, instance)
    );
}

// Router for proprioception
export const proprioceptionRouter = (zone, instance) => {
    return (
        router.get("/proprioception/" + zone, instance)
    );
}
```

---

In the index.js

```
// Routes for 
import mobilityRouter from "./routes/mobility/mobilityAPI.js";

const app = express();

//for mobility URL
app.use("/", mobilityRouter);
```

When I copy past the 'mobilityRouter' function and use it in the import file it works perfectly, but once I put it in another file and exports it I have a "cannot GET/" in my browser. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have different instances of router in both files. Either pass router as a parameter to the function in the other file or export & import in your routerLogic.js.

Comment: probably better to import the functions and the router to the entrpoint and add the functions as handler to the 1 router instance.

Comment: @The Fool yes correct. Router instance in index.js would be better IMHO.